# Movement through argument list

Tags: emacs, elisp, cc-mode

I'm a C++ programmer using a setup consisting of `cc-mode` and `CEDET` and of course our beloved emacs (v24.2).

A feature I'm missing is a function that moves point fast through a list of arguments. Consider this example:

```cpp
void takesManyArgs( int a1, int a2, int a3, std::pair<int,int> a4, int a5 ){  
    // does something nifty!  
}  
// [...]
takesManyArgs( b1, b2, b3, make_pair( b4, b5 ), b6 );
```

Where point is just before the first `int`. Now I'd like to an easy way to quickly move through the list of arguments, i.e. a `forward-argument` (and `backward-argument` aswell) function that moves right before the first non-whitespace character past the comma (the argument separator).
I have written a small function that does it but it's not quite the way I'd like it work:

```lisp
(defun arg-forward ()  
  "Move point forward in the file until we hit an argument separator, i.e. comma, colon or semicolon."  
  (interactive)  
  (progn  
    (re-search-forward "[,]")))
```

In principle this function just jumps to the next comma. That's not the behaviour I want.

I'd like a function that:

- **Edit:** Jumps to the next argument separator (i.e. comma for C++) and places point just after that argument separator
- Checks whether there's a whitespace after the comma; in case there's one, point is moved to the first non-whitespace character (i.e. instead of `,| int` it will look like `, |int` where `|` marks point)
- Stops at the end of the argument list and prints a message (e.g. "At end of argument list")
- Stays within its "scope", i.e. it'll go from `|int b3` to `|make_pair( int b4, int b5 )` to `|int a6` where `|` marks point

Any help from you `elisp` "hackers" is appreciated!

**Edit:** Added some clarification.
**Edit2:** Fixed that example "Code"

Comment: You might want to change your example since the code you present does not seem to be valid C++: `make_pair(int a4, int a5)` is not a type and cannot appear like this in a function declaration/definition.

Comment: @Francesco The code in the question is certainly wrong, but similar constructs can appear with default argument. Classic C++.

Comment: Yeah... that's right. I added the make_pair halfway into writing this question (of course it was supposed to go in the function call) and didn't really check for correct code. Fixed it anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function seems to do what you requested:

```
(defun arg-forward ()
  "Move point forward until we hit an argument separator, the comma, colon, semicolon"
  (interactive)
  (condition-case nil
      (let ((separator-regexp "[,:;]"))
        (forward-sexp)
        (while (not (or (looking-at (format "[ \t]*%s" separator-regexp))
                        (save-excursion (forward-char -1)
                                        (looking-at (format "[]\"')}]*[ \t]*%s " separator-regexp)))))
          (forward-sexp))
        (if (looking-at separator-regexp)
            (forward-char 1))
        ;; going forward one sexp and back puts point at front of sexp
        ;; essentially skipping the whitespace, but also ensuring we don't
        ;; jump out of a larger closing set of parentheses 
        (forward-sexp)
        (forward-sexp -1))
    (error
     (beep)
     (message "At end of argument list"))))
```

Comment: I tested it and it doesn't stop at the argument separator (comma). For `( int aa, int ab, make_pair( int ac, int ad ), int ae, int af )``with poin just before `int aa` it'll jump to `int ae` instead of the chain `|int ab` -> `|make_pair( int ac, int ad)` -> `|int ae` where `|` marks point.

Comment: @elemakil Sorry, I tested it in lisp mode, not C++ mode, and the `forward-sexp` works slightly differently there.  I just updated the answer with a fix for C++ mode.

Comment: There's still one minor bug. Consider this: `|int aa , int ab, int ac` where `|` marks the point. `arg-forward` moves the right before `int ac`, i.e. in case that there's a trailing space before the argument separator the next argument is omitted. Maybe this is easy to fix aswell? OTher than that it works like a charm!

Comment: Trying that function out on some code, there are two bugs. Consider this: `|int aa,int ab, int ac` where `|` marks the point. The function will omit arguments if there's no space _after_ the argument separator: point is placed just before `int ac`. In case that there's a space before the separator but none after point will be placed _before_ the separator (i.e. `|int aa ,int ab` -> `int aa |,int ab`). I guess the (regular?) expression `(format "[ \t]*%s" separator-regexp)` must be changed for this, but I don't know what `%s` it (whitespace char?).

Comment: Although I'd never format my code like the two bugged scenarios above I'd be glad if you could fix it :) So far, the elisp functions you posted on SA have been a great addition to my dotemacs and I'd like to add one more.

Comment: Well, I fixed the second bug (i.e. space before separator, no space after) by adding the if statement (the only one so far in your code) just after the final `forward-sexp -1` (but in the `let` block). There seems to be no solution for the "no-space before **and** after separator" bug when using `forward-sexp` but maybe you can help?

Answer (score 3):

You could write a function that uses `forward-sexp` and checks to see if you're at one of "argument separator" or "end of argument list".

I don't seem to have an emacs handy right now, so I can't trivially check an example implementation, but with those at hand, you should be well on your way.

Untested code below:

```
(defun forward-argument ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((argument-terminator "[),]"))              ;; Arguments stop at commas or close
     (while (not (looking-at argument-terminator)) ;; until we're at end-of-argument...
        (forward-sexp 1))))                        ;; move forward
```

This could probably benefit from pulling the argument-terminator out into a defvar, so it's easy to make it mode-specific. It could probably benefit from having a count prefix (wrap it in a (while (> count 0) ... (setq count (1- count)) and default count to 1 if no prefix is given) and a few other things., Not to mention actually checking the code against a live emacs instead of trying to remember what arguments functions take and what they're called.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using CEDET with your C++ code, you can take advantage of the TAG navigation commands.  I tried this with the version of CEDET from the CEDET bzr repository.

Check in the Development menu, near the bottom is Navigate Tags.  You will find keybindings for forward/backward tag on:

`C-c , n`  - next tag

`C-c , p`  - previous tag

These will move you between functions, between arguments, between all sorts of things.

These functions don't do all the things you were asking about, but are a good start.

Comment: This works fine for function declarations/definitions but not for function calls.